# Sharing Large Database Backup Among Team

Tags: backups

I work on a team of three - five developers that work on an ASP.net web application remotely. We currently run a full local database from a recent backup on all of our machines during development. The current backup, compressed, is about 18 GB.

I'm looking to see if there's an easier way to keep all of our local copies relatively fresh without each of us individually downloading the 18 GB file over HTTP from our web server on a regular basis. I guess FTP is an option, but it won't speed the process up at all.

I'm familiar with torrents and the thought keeps hitting me that something like that would be effective, but I'm unsure of the security or the process.

Comment: Wouldn't cloning it on a centralized server be an option? We have a testdatabase with about 120 GB that we use that way when we need the complete database. For most other development tasks I prefer a far smaller test database with a few "typical" entries.

Comment: The main problem with that is that all of our servers are behind a firewall and only allow HTTP traffic and VPN for RDP. Having the entire database locally allows offline development as well.

Comment: If all you want to do is speed up transfers of the DB so that you're all using the same copy each day, you could torrent it. Put a tracker on the server and each dev/test has a client running.

Comment: Might be worth to invest in a server located closer to the developers.

Comment: Other tools you might want to research are rsync/deltacopy which only transmits the delta, or ant/nant tasks to download it at night/weekend.

Comment: The question I'd be asking myself is "do I actually need the entire database for everyday dev?"

Answer (score 2):

Does your database support incremental backups or log shipping?  If so, you might try one of those, and just update the database instead of doing a complete restore.  This won't give much advantage if your DB structure changes a lot, but if it's mostly data changes then this could save you a good deal of time (and network bandwidth).

Answer (score 0):

rsync or some other copy-only-differences system. Deltas between two subsequent db dumps ought to be pretty similar.

Answer (score 0):

Do they need all the data?
If yes, what they can do is creating the database but empty, then add some data they need to be able to work. Like this, they save bandwidth and time.

Or when you perform backups, you create one but you remove the unnecessary part. It will make your backup lightweight and faster to download.